# pip not working in python 3.5 on Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7-x64

I have installed python 3.5 on my Windows 7 machine. When I installed it, I marked the check box to install `pip`. After the installation, I wanted to check whether pip was working, so I typed `pip` on the command line and hit enter, but did not respond. The cursor blinks but it does not display anything.

Please help.

Regards.

Comment: Since I'm not using Windows 7 as my OS I can't mark any answer as it solved my problem or most useful answer here(I apologize). please `up-vote` any answer which helped you or solved your problem so it'll help others to take the right decision. regards.

Answer (score 28):

Add the Script folder of python to your environment path

or you can do this from command line:

```
 python -m pip install package-name
```

Comment: Path was added. It did not work. I tried the given command It gave me errors

Comment: Finally managed to install the package using command line. Thanks.

Comment: try `python -m pip -h` if that work, then pip is working and you can uses as `python -m pip`...

Comment: I get an error: `C:\python351\python.exe: No module named pip`

Answer (score 8):

1. go the windows cmd prompt
2. go to the python directory
3. then type python -m pip install package-name

Answer (score 6):

run it at the cmd window, not inside the python window.  it took me forever to realize my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem on Windows 10, This is how I fix it:

1. Click the *search* icon and type **System Environment**
2. In *System Properties* click on **Environment Variables**
3. In *System Variables* tab click **New**
4. Enter **PYTHON3_SCRIPTS** for the *variable name* and `C:\Users\YOUR USER NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts` for *Variable Value*. *Don't forget to change (YOUR USER NAME) in the path with your **user**, And to change your **Python version** or just go to this path to check it `C:\Users\YOUR USER NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`*
5. Click **OK**
6. Click **NEW** again!
7. Enter **PYTHON3_HOME** for the *variable name* and `C:\Users\YOUR USER NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\` for *Variable Value*. *Don't forget to change (YOUR USER NAME) in the path with your **user**, And to change your **Python version** or just go to this path to check it `C:\Users\YOUR USER NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`*
8. Click **OK**
9. Find **Path** in the same tab *select it* and click **Edit**
10. Click **New** and type `%PYTHON3_SCRIPTS%` Then click **OK**

Now, everything is set. Restart your **Terminal** and `pip` should be working now.

Comment: For the record, Now I'm using Windows 10 and I didn't have problems installing pip here. Anyway, your answer will be helpful to someone else for sure :)
Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Version 3.5.2.

Have you tried `py.exe -m install package-name`? This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you open a command prompt, use:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

then

```
python -m pip install <<package-name>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Pycharm, an easy way is go to file>setting>project interpreter. Click on the + icon you will find on right side probably and then search and install required library.

Answer (score -1):

For those with several python versions of python 3 installed in windows: I solved this issue by executing the pip install command directly from my python35 Scripts folder in cmd...for some reason pip3 pointed to python 34 even though python 35 was set first in environmental variables.

Answer (score -1):

I had the issue, and answered this same question sometimes ago. Do open a cmd if in windows OS or linux OS with admistrative privilege. Then  python -m pip install --upgrade pip

then

python -m pip install <>

Answer (score -1):

Working on windows and above version than **3.0**

First upgrade pip to pip3 by following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

Then install maximum package by following command:

```
pip3 install <package_name>
```

I never wrote all package because some package not support to pip or pip3 command.

Comment: Did you try this with Windows 7?. I asked just to make sure.